# Try to get data from sql with eval

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to get data from sql but I couldn't find how to use.
`<a href="#">` I want to get url link from database into link and try to add `<img src="#">` image path from database.

I can get data from database for Literal. But cant find for html tags.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="LinksRepeater" runat="server" 
                            OnItemDataBound="LinksRepeater_ItemDataBound">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <li>
            <a href="#">
                <span class="icon"></span>
                <asp:Literal ID="LinksTitleLiteral" Text="" runat="server" />
                <span class="menu-icon">
                    <img src="img/Coderbits.png" alt="Ana Sayfa" />
                </span>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the field containing image path is named `ImageUrl` you could simply do

```
<img src="<%# Eval("ImageUrl") %>" alt="Ana Sayfa" />
```

And the same for anchor tags

```
<a href="<%# Eval("LinkUrl") %>">link</a>
```